# C# and Entity Framework Core : it fails to save records after exception caught for saving invalid data to another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have to tables. one is for tasks and the other to manage widgets. a task is created to update widgets with a status of "submitted". Once it processes the task it updates the status to "complete" or "error".

When I process the task and try to update the widget table with invalid data (insert null data into a non nullable field in the database as an example), an exception is thrown but I cannot update the task entry with status of "error".

Please do not comment about checking for data consistency. The following code is fictional. My actual code is processing a bunch of data from other places that may or may not have data inconsistency. I am just trying to understand why the following code fails to update the task table when an exception is thrown

```
public void createWidget(int taskID, int widgetID, int? widgetCount)
{
    using (opxContext context = new opxContext())
    {
        var task = context.tasks.Where(x => x.taskId == taskID).First();

        try
        {
            var widget = context.Widget.Where(x => x.widgetId == widgetID).First();

            Widget widget = new Widget 
                                { 
                                    widgetID = widgetID, 
                                    widgetCount = widgetCount 
                                };

            context.Widget.add(widget); //exception may be thrown if count is null, count cannot be null

            task.taskStatus = "complete";
            context.SaveChanges();  

            Console.WriteLine("complete");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            task.taskErrors = e.message;
            task.taskStatus = "error";
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(e.message); //error message is displayed but the task in the database is not updated
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

}

```
The following code below works. Is there something in my initial code that is causing the records to not be updated during the exception code?

    public void createWidget(int taskID, int widgetID, int? widgetCount)
    {
        try
        {
            using (opxContext context = new opxContext())
            {
                var widget = context.Widget.Where(x => x.widgetId == widgetID).First();

                Widget widget = new Widget { widgetID = widgetID, widgetCount = widgetCount };
                context.Widget.add(widget); //exception may be thrown if count is null, count cannot be null
                context.SaveChanges();

                var task = context.tasks.Where(x => x.taskId == taskID).First();
                task.taskStatus = "complete";
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            using (opxContext context = new opxContext())
            {
                var task = context.tasks.Where(x => x.taskId == taskID).First();
                task.taskErrors = e.message;
                task.taskStatus = "error";

                context.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine(e.message); //error message is displayed but the task in the database is not updated
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first example, you have added widget to the context, whenever you call context SaveChanges, it will try to commit widget and will throw exception, you had your first exception on Try block, then again you will get another exception on the catch too, both exceptions is because context is trying to commit widget to database.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did realize shortly after posting what the problem was. I also realized I could clear the change tracker which would remove the faulty entry
context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
I would just have to be careful to make sure I am not removing any changes that may have also taken place in the createWidget method.